# OCaml int to binary string conversion

Tags: ocaml, type-conversion

What's the easiest way to convert an `Int32.t` to binary? For example:
-1 -> "\255\255\255\255" ?

Edit:
To use extlib, install it with yum and in the toplevel:

```
#use "topfind";;
#require "extlib";;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [extlib](http://ocaml-extlib.googlecode.com/svn/doc/apiref/IO.html#VALwrite_i32):

```
# let io = IO.output_string ();;
val io : string IO.output = <abstr>
# IO.write_i32 io (-1);;
- : unit = ()
# IO.close_out io;;
- : string = "\255\255\255\255"
```

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest using [Bitstring](http://people.redhat.com/~rjones/bitstring/html/Bitstring.html) for this kind of thing.  You can find it [here](http://code.google.com/p/bitstring/).

For example, in the toplevel:

```
# #use "topfind";;
# #camlp4o;;
# #require "unix";;
# #require "bitstring.syntax" ;;
# let data = Int32.of_int (-1);;
# let bits = BITSTRING { data: 32 } ;;
```

then you can perform various conversions on the bitstring including writing it to a binary file or to stdout or to a string:

```
# Bitstring.string_of_bitstring bits ;;
- : string = "\255\255\255\255"
```